# GWT - Relational Database with Drag and Drop Operations

Tags: java, gwt, drag-and-drop, relational-database, gxt

I am a student and want to make the final draft with a Dynamic Schedule Manager.
It was proposed to work in Java. Restriction: Should use GWT with GXT (optional) + Relational Database (eg MySql) and will operate with a Drag and Drop library.

The Drag and Drop operations are going to communicate directly with the database, eg drag a student for a class. 
You should make an insert in the student's respective table. 
It's an interesting challenge, but requires a lot of knowledge.

The question I ask is if anyone has experience doing something similar and could advise me where to start, 
what technologies to use (eg to Relational Database), best approaches, tips and so on.

**Note:** I've already draw Database, started learning the Google Web Toolkit docs.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

> For drag&drop:

Examples:
http://gwtquery-plugins.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/droppable/demo/GwtPortletSample/GwtPortletSample.html

Check out the project at:
http://code.google.com/p/gwtquery-plugins/wiki/DragAndDropPluginForGWTDeveloppers

> For GWT

I suggest you stay away from GXT (it can be pretty daunting to ingest GWT and GXT all at once, believe me!). Plain GWT should be enough for your app.

> For domain data model
>   Persistence is not that easy. Are you working all of this alone?! I've gone through a lot of trouble get things working together. So I suggest you use persistence packages like Datanucleus or Hibernate. Make your data model as simple as possible, it will save you time.

Pretty big project you have there. Also, don't start from scratch. Search a GWT project in code.google.com which is maintained for you to accelerate development. Here is one example using GWT + Maven + Objectify.

http://code.google.com/p/listwidget/

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you **code-gijoe**. This will be a huge challenge for me. What scares me is encode the objects for Drag and Drop and save them with persistence. 
Regarding persistence, i was thinking in MySql. You spoke of using Hibernate. 
I'll take a look at Hibernate. 
Regarding GXT, only considered because of the library for Drag n'Drop but maybe I'll follow your advice and 
I will leave it for behind. I'll just use GWT. It will be very hard ...

Comment: Drag&Drop with what I sent you is pretty easy. You create a drageable GWT element (could be a simple list box). You create a drop target (could be another list box). Build this up with a simple GWT project (from the sample GWT project in eclipse with GWT pluggin). Use the UIBinder capabilities from GWT. Don't use the Activities/MVP and other advanced stuff. You could have a couple of java files and xml and that's it. The persistence could be done later. Just keep in mind you'll need a few GWT-RPC async services to send/get data!